# How to add custom models in Lazypredict

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am using Lazypredict to run multiple classification models, as my dataset is huge, I am not able to run all the models which are pre-selected in LazyClassifier, rather than using all the models, I am trying to use some selected models i.e. Random Forest and Decision Tree etc. Below is my sample script, But I am getting an error that Custom_Models is not available, May I know if there is any other way to select the customs models in LazyClassifier, I am using 0.2.12 version of lazy predict.

#Updated code as per below suggestion, but still i am getting error,
Below is my script,

```
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

#Updated Line
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0,ignore_warnings=True, custom_metric=None, predictions=True , classifiers=['random_forest', 'logistic_regression', 'k_nearest_neighbor'])
models, predictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

error message:

```
    'str' object has no attribute '__name__' Invalid Classifier(s)
     too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`custom_model` is removed [in the latest version](https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict/blob/aad245d602f080575d05ec68750fa9c229aeea30/lazypredict/Supervised.py#L205). I see the new param `classifiers` which accepts list, so maybe you can try:

```py
..., classifiers=['random_forest', 'logistic_regression', 'k_nearest_neighbor'])
```

Comment: After adding the following code, i am getting this error 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Comment: try adding `predictions=True` as another param in the `clf` line as well

Comment: I updated my code and error msg, plz do check it and help me resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

error message:

```
'str' object has no attribute '__name__' Invalid Classifier(s)
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

means we try to call the object. So we need to import the object instead.

```
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble._forest import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model._logistic import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors._classification import KNeighborsClassifier

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Updated Line
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0,
                     ignore_warnings=True,
                     custom_metric=None,
                     predictions=True,
                     classifiers=[RandomForestClassifier, LogisticRegression, KNeighborsClassifier])
models, predictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
print(models[:3])
```

Result:

```
                        Accuracy  Balanced Accuracy  ... F1 Score  Time Taken
Model                                                ...                     
RandomForestClassifier      0.98               0.98  ...     0.98        0.12
LogisticRegression          0.98               0.98  ...     0.98        0.01
KNeighborsClassifier        0.98               0.98  ...     0.98        0.01
```